# How to reference an anchor tag of local server address

Tags: html, url, rack

Is there a way to reference an anchor tag through a local host address. like 0.0.0.0:3000 for rails or 0.0.0.0:9292 for a rack app. With rails you could always use pow to do the hosting. it will humanize the url to appname.dev/#thing. which will work. in my case i am trying to do this in a rack app.

like 0.0.0.0:9292#hello or 0.0.0.0:9292/#hello

It keeps taking me to a google search.
The reason i am asking this question is because i would like to test a fancy-box that i am trying to open from the URL using an anchor. i don't want to be testing this in production.

things i have tried -> on Chrome, Firefox and Safari

```
http://0.0.0.0:9292/#speaker1
http://0.0.0.0:9292#speaker1
0.0.0.0:9292/#speaker1
0.0.0.0:9292#speaker1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid ip adress. It's reference to the network containing all ip addresses. So I'd recommend trying

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#hello
```

to access localhost

Answer (score 1):

isn't localhost 127.0.0.1?

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

> In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a
>   non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non
>   applicable target.

If you are using hosts file to redirect `127.0.0.1` to that ip, try using a valid ip address!

and the other thing you should do is use `127.0.0.1/#hello` instead of `127.0.0.1#hello` to avoid confusions!

Comment: yeah i mean local host from a rails server is 0.0.0.0:3000, or a rackapp being 0.0.0.0:9292.